# Error installing MxNet for python with pip due to awsebcli

Tags: python, pip, aws-cli, mxnet

I was following Apache's instructions to install MxNet for Python on a MacOS (CPU): http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/install/index.html

However, when I get to the line

```
pip install mxnet --pre
```

I run into the issue where it quits installing due to the following error:

> awsebcli 3.12.4 has requirement requests<=2.9.1,>=2.6.1, but you'll have requests 2.18.4 which is incompatible.

If someone could help me figure out what's going on, that would be really helpful. I'm running this on a Macbook Pro with High Sierra and Python 3.6.5 on it as well as EB CLI 3.12.4

EDIT: I tried using (as suggested):

```
pip install requests==2.9.1
```

However, it results in

> awsebcli 3.12.4 has requirement requests<=2.9.1,>=2.6.1, but you'll have requests 2.18.4 which is incompatible.
>
> Installing collected packages: requests
>
> Found existing installation: requests 2.9.1
>
> Uninstalling requests-2.9.1:
>
> Successfully uninstalled requests-2.9.1
>
> Successfully installed requests-2.18.4

This prevents me from finishing my installation of MxNet and I'm unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a higher version of `requests` than needed for `awsebcli`. Try installing the lower version if that works for you:

```
pip install requests==2.9.1
```

Comment: Hey! So, I tried your advice but now I'm getting the following error:
"awsebcli 3.12.4 has requirement requests<=2.9.1,>=2.6.1, but you'll have requests 2.18.4 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: requests
  Found existing installation: requests 2.9.1
    Uninstalling requests-2.9.1:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.9.1
Successfully installed requests-2.18.4"

MxNet still won't install despite moving down to a lower version of requests. Do you have any suggestions of what to do?

Comment: @ssmost Ok, looks like the package you are installing is trying to install `requests` that is not compatible with `requests` version required by `awsebcli`. Looks like `awsebcli`'s latest version is `3.13`. How about upgrading `awsebcli` first then?